# Parcel build and start commands work but JavaScript files are not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, package.json, parceljs

I've been creating a personal website that uses a ColorLib template and bootstrap css to house some personal and professional information for potential employers. I have it exactly how I want it to look and function when I run it on an Apache server but now I want to deploy to a hosting service like Render. I've been tinkering with Parcel in my package.json for my build and start commands and I finally got them to work. I was having a lot of issues since some of my CommonJS scripts incorporated require(jquery) code which was a big nono and I couldn't properly turn the scripts into ES6 modules. I bypassed this by using CDNs instead but I'm not too sure why this worked (any enlightenment on this would be appreciated).
EDIT: Turns out I didn't bypass them and just deferred the errors until later, I guess due to loading times/priority. I am getting these errors in my console:

```
jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2  Uncaught TypeError: r.getClientRects is not a function
    at ce.fn.init.offset (<anonymous>:2940:26)
    at e._detectViewport (<anonymous>:148:43)
    at e.init (<anonymous>:107:186)
    at new e (<anonymous>:3:103)
    at <anonymous>:252:72
    at Function.each (<anonymous>:122:59)
    at ce.fn.init.each (<anonymous>:56:23)
    at a.fn.<computed> [as stellar] (<anonymous>:251:55)
    at <anonymous>:7:15
    at <anonymous>:320:3
```

As well as:

```
jquery.stellar.min.js:2  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at e._reset (<anonymous>:214:36)
    at e.refresh (<anonymous>:142:38)
    at <anonymous>:135:19
    at dispatch (<anonymous>:1455:270)
    at v.handle (<anonymous>:1418:106)
```

When I inspect the page sources, it seems the index page should be exactly what I want and all the proper distributed folders of JS and CSS are there. Back when I was working through the require(jquery) issues, my page would still load with my photos but the JS wouldn't be loading because all my issues were coming from JS.

My package.json is like so:

```
{
  ...
  "source": "./src/index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build ./src/index.html --public-url ./",
    "start": "parcel"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "puppeteer": "^21.1.1",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cssnano": "^6.0.1",
    "parcel": "^2.9.3",
    "postcss": "^8.2.15"
  }
}
```

I tried changing my source dir to ./dist/ but that hasn't done anything and updating my start command to be more specific to ./src/index.html which also doesn't change anything. I have to keep "main" out of my package.json since I don't use index.js.

I don't use an index.js file as my site is very close to static, I just use some Node.js scripts to scrape some data and house it in my data folders. I've been trying to achieve this using a GitHub Jobs that runs the files at a specified time that way it will push, deploy and the only thing changed will be some data files for the site to load again (just updated but from the same dir). This has been the easiest way of achieving this that I've found so far but any insight is welcome.

Here are my scripts as well:

```
<script src="./js/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.4.1/jquery-migrate.min.js" integrity="sha512-KgffulL3mxrOsDicgQWA11O6q6oKeWcV00VxgfJw4TcM8XRQT8Df9EsrYxDf7tpVpfl3qcYD96BpyPvA4d1FDQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js" integrity="sha512-0QbL0ph8Tc8g5bLhfVzSqxe9GERORsKhIn1IrpxDAgUsbBGz/V7iSav2zzW325XGd1OMLdL4UiqRJj702IeqnQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js" integrity="sha512-IsNh5E3eYy3tr/JiX2Yx4vsCujtkhwl7SLqgnwLNgf04Hrt9BT9SXlLlZlWx+OK4ndzAoALhsMNcCmkggjZB1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-fHY2UiQlipUq0dEabSM4s+phmn+bcxSYzXP4vAXItBvBHU7zAM/mkhCZjtBEIJexhOMzZbgFlPLuErlJF2b+0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="./js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/aos.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scrollax@1.0.0/scrollax.min.js"></script>
    
<script src="./js/main.js"></script>
```